# Resizing image view in table cell iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am developing an iPhone app where downloading a high quality image from my app server. I am required to resize it to half its size and display it in the table cell. Could anyone help me to find which functions I could use?

Appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageWithData:yourdata];
UIImageView *imageViewToPutInCell = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:yourImage];
imageViewToPutInCell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, yourImage.size.width / 2, yourImage.size.height / 2);
```